# SQL Count depending on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a MySQL table called year.

I want to check how many rows I have for each `DISTINCT year`.

This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year FROM `table`
```

Gets each year, but how do I hook each `year` inside of a `COUNT` statement? Do I have to use a nested query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, year FROM `videos` GROUP BY year
```